# SEAM Transactions in Weblogic

Tags: seam, weblogic, transactions

I am trying to use SEAM managed transactions in my application (using  in components.xml) deployed in Weblogic 10.3. The application deploys succesfully but when I load the start page it is never loaded. Does anyone have a clue why this is happening?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure this is related to Seam Managed Transactions? Can you turn off managed transactions and you are able to hit your start page? Also, have you attempted to debug the code that the start page is supposed to hit (assuming you are hitting an action class that is performing a transaction).

Comment: Yes I have turned off transactions and my page loads correctly. As soon as I turn it on, the page seems to load (the code on the backend is ran) but the page is never displayed).

Comment: May be this will help http://stackoverflow.com/q/7173474/808237