# WebLogic 10.5.3 + Seam 2.2.1: Application does not start

Tags: weblogic-10.x, java-ee-5, seam2

we have a WAR packaged web application which works on a development machine. It consists of Java EE 5 + Seam 2.2.1 + Hibernate 3.3.1. It uses an Oracle 10g XE database and runs on the latest Tomcat 6 using JDK 1.6.0_24. The system is a 64bit Windows 7 Pro and uses Firefox 6.

Now, we tried to migrate the application to Oracle WebLogic 10.3.5. We followed the Seam manual for specifying the datasource, deploying the JSF lib and configuring the necessary xml-Files. In parallel to that, we verified that a newly seam-gen generated application using the same datasource and having the xml files configured as stated works fine.

But if we try our own application on WebLogic, allthough the deployment works fine, when trying to open the web application in the browser, it shows that endless redirection occured. We don't see any stacktrace or log error, even when configuring log4j in WebLogic. When analyzing the request with Firebug, we see the get request to "login.seam" and then 20 times a get request for "error.seam" (or "debug.seam when setting debug mode) with the response "302 Moved Temporarily".

I worked on that all week now, trying to compare all configurations and couldn't solve it - so I hope to get any ideas what could cause that problem and how to solve it!

Comment: did you try to disable seam security? May be you secured your error/debug page, which leads to redirects...

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could pin down the problem to starting a transaction on the JTA persistence context.
I still don't understand why I didn't see any log message or stacktrace and why this also happens on the debug/error page (that's why the endless redirect occured).

I ended up using RESOURCE_LOCAL so far, but I'm not sure if this is the right thing to do.
The alternative is disabling the seam transaction setting, but then it didn't work together with the development build which still runs on Tomcat.